# How to resize indicators of UIPageControl in iOS 4?

Tags: ios4, uipagecontrol, indicator

How do I customise indicators for UIPageControl. I tried accessing [this link](http://apptech.next-munich.com/2010/04/customizing-uipagecontrols-looks.html) but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use SMPageControl.  Works very much like UIPageControl but you can easily customize the indicators (using setPageIndicatorImage) and selected indicators (setCurrentPageIndicatorImage).